# Grails Form POST with missing params when form Content-Type = text

Tags: grails, post, controller, content-type

I've a controller action where a third party application posts data,
the problem is that the POST request params are empty, this is due to POST Content-Type = 'text'.
If I simulate (with Chrome Rest Console plugin) the same POST with Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
then the request params are correctly filled.

How can I enable POST data with Content-Type = 'text'?

Comment: Any reason for doing that? Tell them to send you formal post request.

Comment: sadly the POST request cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can access the raw POST data using

```
request.reader.text
```

As far as I can tell (and I might be wrong) grails won't parse this content type, because it ultimately uses `HTTPServletRequest`, which only parses `www-form-urlencoded`, as this is the normal way to pass variable values thorugh HTTP.

You can easily emulate the behaviour you desire by using a grails filter, such as this:

```
class TextRequestFilters {
    def filters= {
        textRequestFilter(controller: '*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                if(request.post && request.format == 'text') {
                    String postBody = request.reader.text
                    String[] variables = postBody.split('&')
                    variables.each { String variable ->
                        String[] parts = variable.split('=')
                        String key = URLDecoder.decode(parts[0], request.characterEncoding)
                        String value = URLDecoder.decode(parts[1], request.characterEncoding)
                        params[key] = value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

You probably want to exclude asset requests and such from this filter.

Content type should be `text/plain`, as this is what grails translates to text format out of the box, but I belive you can set this up in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to have params filled like a normal POST avoiding to parse request.reader.text

Comment: I've updated my answer to describe a more comfortable way to use this.